# How do I figure out and change which version of Java Maven is using to execute?

Tags: java, maven

When running our Maven build, a member of my team gets a NoSuchMethodError in one of the dependant plug-ins when executing. However, when we run `java -version` from her command line, it indicates Java 1.6.0_26.  The error obviously seems to be screaming that Maven is using Java 5.

How do I figure out and change what version of Java is being used by Maven?

3 potentially important notes:

1. This is executed at the command line, not using Eclipse plugin
2. JAVA_HOME is set to a Java 1.6 JDK
3. Using Maven 2.2.1

Comment: Seems JDK 1.6.0_26 is used to compile your source with 1.5. This is possible!

Comment: eek! :( "this error" link has broken

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`mvn -version` will output which java it's using. If JAVA_HOME is set to a valid JDK directory and Maven is using something else, then most likely someone has tampered with the way that Maven starts up.

Comment: You can define the Java to be used with maven. See the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813828/why-maven-use-jdk-1-6-but-my-java-version-is-1-7

Answer (score 14):

You will need to configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to use 1.6 `source` and `target` parameters ( by default it is 1.5 ).

This is the best done in your project's parent pom in `<pluginManagment>` section ( but you can always configure it per individual projects of course ).

```
  <build>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>

          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 3):

`mvn -version` tells you what compiler Maven is using, so this answers the question *unless* your POM specifies override values for the versions to be used.

Here's the easiest way to specify the overrides in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Alternatively, the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) can be specified more explicitly.  In that case, look at the `<source>` and `<target>` values associated with the plugin.

Both of these options are described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

**If your POM has a `<parent>`, then you need to check that as well (recursively).**

*Note: When `source` and `target` are specified, these values are passed as command-line options to the compiler.  Using this feature, you can compile or run against earlier Java versions than the compiler's nominal value.*

Comment: An example of how to set the *compiler* if you don't want to simply use `javac` from your path: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 mvn clean install`.  Your-mileage-may-vary in terms of how/when this can be overridden under Maven.

Comment: As an ultimate sanity check, you could ask `javac`/`java` from within the build environment by setting the build parameters to add `-version` to the command-line argument -- similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079415/86967) (for Gradle).

Comment: `<java.version>` in `pom.xml` is not relevant to this: [Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38882080/86967)

Comment: Remember that `JAVA_HOME` could be already set in your environment -- overriding the `PATH` variable.

Comment: This seems like it could be important, if it wasn't so ridiculous: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html