# Why Maven uses JDK 1.6 but my java -version is 1.7

Tags: java, linux, macos, maven

I have setup maven in my terminal, and when getting the version settings (using `mvn -v`) it seems it uses JDK 1.6, while I have JDK 1.7 installed. Is there anything wrong?

The commands I enter are these:

```
blues:helloworld Ninja$ java -version
```

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_05"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)`
> ```

```
blues:helloworld Ninja$ mvn -v
```

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 10:15:32+0800)
> Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.1.0/libexec
> Java version: 1.6.0_51, vendor: Apple Inc.
> Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: EUC_CN
> OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
> ```

Comment: Can you post your PATH and JAVA_HOME variables?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky blues:helloworld Ninja$ echo $JAVA_HOME

blues:helloworld Ninja$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky is this you want,sir?

Comment: I'm female (so referring to me as "sir" is incorrect) and yes.  Please try setting your JAVA_HOME.  Your problem seems similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752519/how-to-change-maven-java-home

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky Forgive my rudeness.The url you given is the problem I meet.Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 239, accepted):

add the following to your `~/.mavenrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{jdk-version}/Contents/Home
```

## Second Solution:

`echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: yes,you answer is correct .The  JAVAHOME  is required.I edit the /etc/profile instead

Comment: Well, adding to ~/.mavenrc ensures that other apps are not affected. Only mvn picks up this version of JDK. :)

Comment: Thank you! Finally maven in  Eclipse compiles again...!

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)

Comment: wow.  this is good.  I just realized that the /etc/alternatives mess doesn't help me here.  There is no alternative set up for the whole JDK.  thanks.  Saved me from asking a repeat question.

Comment: .mavenrc solution worked perfectly for me. Also realised I only had JDK 1.8  installed and not JRE 1.8. Thanks Gaurav!

Comment: Excellent. Other recommendations suggested setting /etc/mavenrc similarly. Just as a warning to anyone else: ~/.mavenrc appears to take precedence.

Comment: This seems to work without `export` too (at least in Ubuntu).

Comment: If you are using jenv on a mac, it can be:
```export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"``` for `~/.mavenrc` file.

Comment: When using IntelliJ, it is also possible to set the JRE to be used by Maven via Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Runner

Answer (score 45):

Get into

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
```

and update the `CurrentJDK` symbolic link to point to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/YOUR_JDK_VERSION/Contents/
```

E.g.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo rm CurrentJDK
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/ CurrentJDK
```

Now it shall work immediately.

Comment: The CurrentJDK symlink trick doesn't seem to work any more with maven 3.3.1, but modifying ~/.mavenrc does.

Answer (score 42):

You can also do,

```
<properties>
      ...  

      <!-- maven-compiler-plugin , aka JAVA Compiler 1.7 -->
      <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>

      ...  
</properties>
```

Comment: That doesn't work if maven is running using java 6.  It just crashes with `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project {projectname}: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 27):

You can also explicitly tell maven which java version to compile for. You can try adding the `maven-compiler-plugin` to your pom.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

If you imported a maven project into an IDE, then there is probably a maven setting in your IDE for default compiler that your maven runner is using.

Comment: o，thank you. but I haven't start . I just 'mvn -v'...the reason is I don't assign JAVA_HOME

Comment: Note that only affects your code that is compiled. I ran into this problem and came here because an external library I was using was compiled for Java 7 and Maven was trying to run it with Java 6

Comment: That doesn't work if maven is running using java 6.  It just crashes with `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project {projectname}: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: This will work in case  maven setting in your IDE for default compiler is lower than 1.7, but the installed jdk is higher than 1.7

Answer (score 9):

It helped me. Just add it in your pom.xml.

By default maven compiler plugin uses Java 1.5 or 1.6, you have to redefine it in your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

For Eclipse Users.
If you have a Run Configuration that does clean package for example.

In the Run Configuration panel there is a JRE tab where you can specify against which runtime it should run.
Note that this configuration overrides whatever is in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I am late to this question, but I think the best way to handle JDK versions on MacOS is by using the script described at: http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/

Answer (score 2):

Please check the compatibility. I struggled with `mvn 3.2.1` and `jdk 1.6.0_37` for many hours. All variables were set but was not working. Finally I upgraded `jdk to 1.8.0_60` and `mvn 3.3.3` and that worked. Environment Variables as following:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_60 
MVN_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\apache-maven\apache-maven-3.3.3 
M2=%MVN_HOME%\bin extend system level Path- ;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

@MasterGaurav's solution works perfectly.

I normally put the Java switch statement into a zsh function:

```
alias java_ls='/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | grep -E "\d.\d.\d[,_]" | cut -d , -f 1 | colrm 1 4 | grep -v Home'

function java_use() {
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)
    echo export "JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)" > ~/.mavenrc
    export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
    java -version
}
```

You can run `java_ls` to get all of the available JVMs on your machine,
and then `java_use 1.7` to use 1.7 for both Java and Maven.