# How to set JAVA_HOME in maven in Windows7 correctly

Tags: eclipse, maven, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, java-home

I am facing Issues in running MVN commands from command line though I am able to successfully run with eclipse.

```
> mvn -version

**Maven home:** D:\maven **Java version:** 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
**Java home:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 
etc etc.....

> echo %JAVA_HOME%

D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

User Variable Set `JAVA_HOME` to `D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`; and path to `D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`.

I have already JDK 1.6 installed in default drive C below. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27`,`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7`

As per project requirement, we needed JDK1.7 installed. Due to permission issues (not able to install C drive), I installed JDK 1.7 in path `D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`,`D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre7`.

On Eclipse pointing to JDK1.7 for installed JREs. And able to run all MAVEN Commands via eclipse. But note, the library files for jre is still pointing to C drive lib jar files only and not D drive jar files.(But as eclipse is working good I ignored this!)

But from command line getting error as "Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK". No compiler etc. on running any maven command. Also maven's JAVA_HOME is still pointing to jre of C drive on running mvn -version.

Please help how to correct my problem. (Without uninstalling older version of Java As i dnt have permission to C drive folder)

Thanks in advance for help. :)

Comment: Could you show contents of your path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813828/why-maven-use-jdk-1-6-but-my-java-version-is-1-7