# Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I searched for other solutions on Stackoverflow but I am still having issues. I am trying to run with 1.7 but `Maven` is using 1.6. I am a bit out of ideas as of right now. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <artifactSet>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>org.hamcrest:*</exclude>
              <exclude>org.mockito:*</exclude>
              <exclude>org.objenesis:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </artifactSet>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/license</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>com.mycompany.app.App</Main-Class>
                <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I try to `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean install` I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-appy: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
```

With `mvn -version` the output is:

```
mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T13:58:10-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

This is what others have suggested

```
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Intellij -> preferences -> Compiler -> Java Compiler

[image]

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You have 1.7 target defined either in pom file or in the project settings of idea. Apparently you can't use that with 1.6 JDK. Change the target bytecode to 1.6

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813828/why-maven-use-jdk-1-6-but-my-java-version-is-1-7

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj After you suggestion, I am getting: `Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Comment: you obviously have 1.7.0_55 installed, not 40.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Java used by your Maven is a Java 6, so it won't compile with a target 1.7.

You've set the JAVA_HOME apparently, but you need to make sure you're using the right java version, try `java -version` and make sure it's 1.7+

I've solved my multiple java versions headaches on OS X by using [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be) a tool to managed multiple java environments. You should give it a try and it's installable via Homebrew.

Comment: Give jEnv a try. You might want to activate the export plugin, which will automatically update your JAVA_HOME whenever you switch java runtimes