# spring.profiles.active is not working from the command line

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot: 1.2.2

This is the syntax supplied in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) (I get `Unknown command-line option '--spring.profiles.active'.` when I start using the command)

```
gradlew bootRun --spring.profiles.active=noAuthentication
```

I tried this but it does not work

```
gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=noAuthentication
```

I have found elsewhere that this should work but it does not

```
gradlew bootRun -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=noAuthentication"
```

I added the following to application.properties and it works correctly.

```
spring.profiles.active=noAuthentication
```

How to you pass this argument from the command line?

Comment: You pass the command line args to Gradle not to your Spring Boot app. See this answer to see how to pass args to the app via Gradle bootRun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079244/how-to-pass-jvm-options-from-bootrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it via

```
project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dspring.profiles.active=${project.gradle.startParameter.systemPropertiesArgs['spring.profiles.active']}"]
}
```

And run

```
gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```