# Setting active profile and config location from command line in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a Spring Boot application.

I have three profiles in my application-> **development, staging and production**. So I have 3 files

1. application-development.yml
2. application-staging.yml
3. application-production.yml

My **application.yml** resides inside `src/main/resources`. I have set the active profile in application.yml as :

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development
```

The other 3 profile specific config files are present in `C:\config` folder.

I am using gradle plugin for eclipse. When I try to do a "**bootRun**", I am setting the command line arguments in my gradle configuration in eclipse as

```
 -Dspring.profiles.active=staging -Dspring.config.location=C:\Config
```

However, the command line property is not getting reflected and my active profile is always getting set as development(which is the one that I have mentioned in the `applications.yml` file). Also *C:\Config* folder is not searched for profile specific config files.

I think I am missing something here. I have been trying to figure it out for the  past 2 days. But no luck. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please add your `bootRun` command line also

Comment: I was running it from eclipse and not command line till now. But I tried running from using "gradle bootRun -Dspring.config.location=C:\Config\ -Dspring.profiles.active=staging" and got the same result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had to add this:

```
bootRun {
    String activeProfile =  System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
    String confLoc = System.properties['spring.config.location']
    systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", activeProfile
    systemProperty "spring.config.location", "file:$confLoc"
}
```

And now bootRun picks up the profile and config locations.

Thanks a lot @jst for the pointer.

Comment: This can be even more simpler as following: `bootRun { systemProperties = System.properties }`. This command will copy all parameters passed with `-D` switch with the same keys to `systemProperty` map.

Comment: this seems to be a gradle only solution, is there no genric solution ?

Comment: Where exactly are you adding this? Anywhere in the build.gradle file or in a specific location within the file?

Comment: @user1767316 you can set a environment variable with SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=profile, works like a charm

Answer (score 617):

There are two different ways you can add/override spring properties on the command line.

#### Option 1: Java System Properties (VM Arguments)

It's important that the -D parameters are before your application.jar
otherwise they are not recognized.

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar
```

#### Option 2: Program arguments

```
java -jar application.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.location=c:\config
```

Comment: Order of the -D parameters is really important :)

Comment: how can you achieve this while deploying to say tomcat container? In that case I simply put my war to webapps folder of tomcat, how do I provide the profile info? by setting system properties?

Comment: @prayagupd yes, you can have system properties set in your bash_profile.

Comment: @maneesh yeah, I am using [env variable](https://github.com/prayagupd/eccount-rest/tree/REST-API-load-balancing) `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` exported via `~/.bash_profile`. `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=e2e`

Comment: Can anybody clarify how to tell what relative path IntelliJ is using when it runs this command? For example, if I didn't want to use an absolute path and instead specify  --spring.config.location=my/relative/path/config/

Comment: If you're using Intellij and you want override the spring variables so you should go to `edit Configuration -> Spring Boot Config -> Overrride parameters` and search for the `spring.profiles.active` and set the value that your desire.

Comment: When you say the order is important: Can we pass in both args: -Dspring.profile.active and -Dspring.config.location such that, the profile is set according to the first argument and the property file is picked up according to the second args?
Eg: `java -Dspring.profiles.active=$ENV -Dspring.config.location=file:///aws-secrets-manager/properties/application-$ENV.properties /code/app.jar`

Comment: Option 1 didn't work for me until I added quotes:  **java -jar -D"spring.profiles.active"=prod application.jar**

Comment: When you deploy your spring boot WAR app to tomcat, modify the **tomcat_home/conf/catalina.properties** by adding following properties  **spring.profiles.active=dev/qa/prod**. After the changes restart the tomcat server.

Answer (score 66):

My best practice is to define this as a VM "-D" argument. Please note the differences between spring boot 1.x and 2.x.

The profiles to enable can be specified on the command line:

Spring-Boot 2.x (works only with maven)

```
-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local
```

Spring-Boot 1.x

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

**example usage with maven:**

Spring-Boot 2.x

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local
```

Spring-Boot 1.x and 2.x

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Make sure to separate them with a comma for multiple profiles:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local,foo,bar
```

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local,foo,bar
```

Comment: You mean spring / spring-boot ? (Spring 1x and Spring 2x) !

Comment: @smilyface spring boot. spring boot is also available in different versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot

Comment: I use spring-boot 2.1.3, and `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local` did not work, `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` worked.

Comment: spring-boot 2.2.0: work both:  `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles` and `-Dspring.profiles.active`

Comment: Docs for this answer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run-example-active-profiles

Comment: Any changes for Spring-boot 3 ?

Answer (score 35):

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=staging -Dspring.config.location=C:\Config
```

is not correct.

should be:

```
--spring.profiles.active=staging --spring.config.location=C:\Config
```

Comment: This causes error "Unrecognized option: --spring.config.location"

Comment: -D is the correct way to set Java System properties. --something is a bash parameter.

Comment: --spring.profiles.active work for me, same thing I referred from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: This also works for me when using Run As -> Java Application in Eclipse

Comment: actually BOTH are correct, it depends on how it is used: it can be `java -Dspring.profiles.active=staging -Dspring.config.location=C:\Config your-spring-boot-app.jar` OR `java your-spring-boot.jar --spring.profiles.active=staging --spring.config.location=C:\Config`

Answer (score 31):

There's another way by setting the **OS** environment variable, **SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE**.

for eg :

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev gradle clean bootRun
```

Reference : [How to set active Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

Comment: Yes, and this avoids the need to muck around with the way Gradle hands system properties through to the application.

Comment: This is the neat way. It should also be used to set database users and passwords and other sensitive configurations so they're not checked in version control.

Answer (score 11):

you can use the following command line:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=[yourProfileName] target/[yourJar].jar
```

Answer (score 9):

This will fix your problem on windows :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.profiles"=env
```

Comment: its working, tq. why mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=env not working?

Answer (score 8):

When setting the profile via the **Maven plugin** you must do it via `run.jvmArguments`

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=production"
```

With debug option:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -Dspring.profiles.active=jpa"
```

I've seen this trip a lot of people up..hope it helps

Comment: has changed to `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar`, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html

Comment: @rwenz3l Thanks! that works for me, just upgraded a project from Spring Boot 1 to 2. Now I just add them all in my bashrc...  `springmvn="mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local"`

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem is likely related to your spring.config.location not ending the path with "/".

Quote the docs

> If spring.config.location contains directories (as opposed to files) they should end in / (and will be appended with the names generated from spring.config.name before being loaded).

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. However, when I run  -Dspring.profiles.active=staging -Dspring.config.location=C:\Config\ also gives me the same issue.  Even active profile is not getting reflected. I think for some reason my command line is not getting passed over.

Comment: You should follow the advice given in this question to pass the args to bootRun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079244/how-to-pass-jvm-options-from-bootrun

Answer (score 5):

Michael Yin's answer is correct but a better explanation seems to be required!

A lot of you mentioned that `-D` is the correct way to specify JVM parameters and you are absolutely right. But Michael is also right as mentioned in [Spring Boot Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) documentation.

What is not clear in the documentation, is what kind of parameter it is: `--spring.profiles.active` is a not a standard JVM parameter so if you want to use it in your IDE fill the correct fields (i.e. program arguments)

Answer (score 5):

For me helped to add "/" at the end of profiles location.

```html
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.additional-location=env/ --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Gradle:

```
-Pspring.profiles.active=local
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to automatically pick property file based upon mentioned the profile name in `spring.profiles.active` and the path in `-Dspring.config.location`

```
application-dev.properties
```

If we are running jar in Unix OS then we have to use `/` at the end of `-Dspring.config.location` otherwise it will give below error.

> Error :: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension of config file location 'file:/home/xyz/projectName/cfg' is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/'

### Example

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.location=/home/xyz/projectName/cfg/ -jar /home/xyz/project/abc.jar
```

or

```
java -jar /home/xyz/project/abc.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev --spring.config.location=/home/xyz/projectName/cfg/
```

Answer (score 1):

A way that i do this on intellij is setting an environment variable on the command like so:

[image: test setup on intellij]

In this case i am setting the profile to test

Answer (score 1):

For running the Spring Boot app after packaging on Windows, this command worked.

```
java -jar -D"spring.profiles.active"=prod target/main-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues to run tests with different profiles in command line in springboot. I fixed that by first setting the profile and then running the test command like below :

Step 1 : export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test(for mac/linux) or SET SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test(for windows)

Step2 : ./gradlew test --tests "com.maersk.snd.integrationtest.IntegrationTestPOC"

Above commands can be clubbed together like below :

export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test && ./gradlew test --tests "com.maersk.snd.integrationtest.IntegrationTestPOC"

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addon, if you have a property mentioned in your `application.properties` file and you need to override that property from another config file you can use below property `spring.config.additional-location` (with -D since you pass from command line)
We used to use this because we have one `application.properties` inside the jar and one external one in each of our servers' config folders, which is used to override any server specific properties.