# Overriding inherited CMD in Dockerfile does not always work?

Tags: java, spring, docker

I am getting some inconsistent behavior in connection with overriding CMD in a derived Dockerfile.

The base Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM myVeryBaseImage

ENV WEBAPP_CONTEXT=my-app
WORKDIR /opt/${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}

COPY app/*.jar ./${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar
COPY baseconfig/* ./config/${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}/

CMD java -jar ${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar --Dspring.profiles.active=docker
```

This base image is provided by another team and it would be difficult to change it. I am now composing a bunch of containers where I want to run the same app multiple times, but with different configurations.

So I figured I'd extend the image copying some more configuration into it and running it with a different spring profile:

```
FROM baseImage
COPY config/application-*.properties ./config/${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}/
CMD java -jar ${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE}
```

And in the docker-compose.yml:

```
myapp-foo:
 build: ./myapp-custom
 image: myapp-custom
 environment:
  PROFILE: foo
 volumes:
  - /opt/my-app/foo:/opt/my-app

myapp-bar:
 image: myapp-custom
 environment:
  PROFILE: bar
 volumes:
  - /opt/my-app/bar:/opt/my-app
```

I would have expected to have 2 containers running, using the `application-foo.properties` and `application-bar.properties` respectively.

It seems, though, that both use the appplication-docker.properties , i.e. the `docker` profile defined in the base Dockerfile.

If I change the CMD in the derived Dockerfile completely, it works:

```
CMD echo "${PROFILE}"
```

Output is "foo" and "bar", respectively. Any hints what might be going on?

My versions are:

```
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

**Update:**
After @blackibiza's suggestions, I changed the derived Dockerfile to

```
FROM baseImage
COPY config/application-*.properties ./config/${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}/
ENTRYPOINT /opt/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java
CMD ["-jar", "${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=foo"]
```

Without the docker-compose stuff, just to see how the derived image would look like. I get error messages from java, trying to run the container. Inspecting the image gives the following:

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{.Config.Cmd}} {{.Config.Entrypoint}}' testapp
[-jar ${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=french] [/bin/sh -c /opt/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java]
```

So it still tries to execute `/bin/sh` and not java. That doesn't look like what I would have expected from the documentation.

**Update2:**
Using the JSON-array syntax for CMD triggers another problem:

```
FROM baseImage
COPY config/application-*.properties ./config/${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}/
CMD ["java", "-jar", "${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=foo"]
```

Will not expand the use of `${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}` and therefore result in an error

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile ${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't just copy & paste faulty Java commands. The `-Dspring.profile.active` argument will not be recognized if it comes after the `.jar` file.

Fix the CMD line to be

```
CMD java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE} ${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar
```

and all is well.

See also "[Setting active profile and config location from command line in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot)"

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the override of the entrypoint.
As described [in the Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/),

> If you want to run your  without a shell then you must
>   express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the
>   executable. This array form is the preferred format of CMD. Any
>   additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the
>   array:
>
> **FROM** ubuntu
>
> **CMD** ["/usr/bin/wc","--help"]
>
> If you would like your container to run the same executable every
>   time, then you should consider using ENTRYPOINT in combination with
>   CMD. See ENTRYPOINT.

While with Composer you can override the CMD arguments like [explained here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/):

```
db:
  command: '-d'
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

you should define an ENTRYPOINT, which is in your case:

```
ENTRYPOINT java
CMD ["-jar", "${WEBAPP_CONTEXT}.jar"]
```

In your specific case, I will argue to expose the shell as entry point and override the CMD with a script, like:

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
CMD ["./script.sh"]
```

and in your compose YML:

```
command: './script2.sh'
```

**UPDATE (based on changed question):**

What it's missing is the definition of the variable. In this case, I suggest to use **[ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)** instead of **ENV** to build the container with the permanent value passed in:

```
docker build -t your_image:your_version --build-arg WEBAPP_CONTEXT=your_context .
```

to get a substitution of the value at build time. The ARG has the advantage of being inherited in your child images

Comment: Hi Michele, I am running the same program in the derived and the base image, it's only the one parameter that should change. I wanted to avoid having to repeat the whole litany in a command in the compose file. Shouldn't a CMD in the derived Dockerfile do the same?

Comment: @ArneMertz yes but you are not using the JSON form specified in the Docker reference, as long as you don't use a shell to launch it. Try to define as default ENTRYPOINT java and let CMD configure only the parameter, like: CMD ["${PROFILE}"]

Comment: @ArneMertz IÄve added the suggestion to use ARG instead of ENV for your case, using the JSON approach

Comment: Thanks for your patience :-) The ARG approach will work for `WEBAPP_CONTEXT`, since it's the same for all containers I want to create via the compose file. Using ARG for the spring profile will, however, result in a different image for each container which wanted to avoid.

Comment: then leave only the ENTRYPOINT, delete CMD and when you run your container with command, append the arguments you need @ArneMertz

Comment: **1** setting the entrypoint and providing the arguments via command line gave me the same Java errors as described above in the first Update - `ENTRYPOINT` did not override but _append_ java to the default `/bin/sh -c`. **2** I tried using no command and no entry point in the Dockerfile at all, starting the container via `docker run testimage java -jar -my-app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=foo`, and the container started, but STILL with the `docker` profile active instead of the `foo` profile -.-

Comment: forget the whole thing. The java argument `-Dspring.profile.active` doesn't have any effect, the profile is set in another .profile - not a Docker problem at all.