# Connecting to Cloud SQL private IP from GCE VM application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am checking [Cloud SQL Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) connections from different types of clients. I could successfully make a connection from an application hosted in a GKE cluster which was created as a VPC-native cluster as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips). Having already done this, I was expecting it would be easier to connect to the Private IP from the same application (which is a simple Spring Boot application) hosted in a GCE VM. Contrary to my expectations this does not appear to be so. It is the same Spring Boot application that I am trying to run inside a VM. But it does not seem to be able to connect to the database. I was expecting some connection error but nothing shows up - no exception thrown. What is strange is I am able connect to the Cloud SQL Private IP via `mysql`command line from the same VM but not from within the Spring Boot application. Anyone out there who faced this before?

Comment: Though I suspected this to be an application issue I couldn't see how until now. Just noticed that when I run in GKE I am passing the spring boot profile as an environment variable to the pod template via kube config file. I should be doing the same thing when I run this inside the GCE VM. Hopefully that will fix this issue. Will post an update tomorrow after testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not related Cloud SQL Private IP. As mentioned in my earlier comment, I was passing active profile info via Kubernetes pod configuration. So the Dockerfile did not have this info. To fix the issue, I had to pass active profile info when the program was initialized outside Kubernetes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot) has a lot of helpful answers how to do this. If the program is being started via a `docker run` command the active profile info can be passed as a command line argument. See [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/) for a useful reference.

So to summarize, Cloud SQL Private IP works fine from a CE VM. No special configuration required at GCE VM end to get this working.