# How to configure Spring Boot Run Configuratipon in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I use this command to run my spring application - java -jar `-Dspring.profiles.active=native ddwa-services-app/target/ddwa-services-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but when run the application from IDE, I need to add run configuration, below is the screenshot showing what I have added, but it does not work for me.

[image]

Comment: You can use Jar Application configuration if you want to run it the same way you do it from the command line.

Comment: where should I include this `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=native`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tPfDYXc.png. You specify the path to jar and add `-Dspring.profiles.active=native` to the VM Options.  You don't need the `java -jar` part.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at my working Spring Boot 2.0.4 app configuration, I can suggest you to try these:

- Correct syntax for spring profiles is `--spring.profiles.active=yourprofile` in Program Arguments
- Working directory should be set to your application root folder.

I also don't have separate Active Profiles field highlighted on your screenshot.

This is my working configuration:
[image]

We also run our app as :

```
java -Dproperty=value -jar path/ourapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=ourprofile
```

Actually, both variants of active profile configuration are correct - see [Setting active profile and config location from command line in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31038250/2417043)

Comment: but I use - java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=native ddwa-services-app/target/ddwa-services-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to run form command line, should it not be similar in configuration?

Comment: @abhi we are using --spring.active.profile in both IDE config and our launch scripts. This may be version specific, we are on Spring Boot 2.0.4 . I've added examples