# How to execute a Spring Boot profile and also pass in a command line argument using java -jar command and also with mvn spring-boot:run command?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, profile

I have an application that has two profiles and it also takes a command line argument. I would like to run this application using `java jar` command but everytime I do that, only the `default` profile gets picked up.

**application.properties (default profile)**

```
endpoint=http://localhost:9999/success
```

**application-prod.properties (prod profile)**

```
endpoint=http://prod.server:5000/success
```

I tried executing following commands and both the time only the `default` profile got picked up.

```
java -jar target/app.jar hello 

java -jar target/app.jar hello -Pprod
```

Am I passing the spring boot profile name the correct way ?

Also please advise if this can be achieved using `mvn spring-boot:run` command?

Comment: java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks Wilem, that worked. Any idea on how to do the same using `mvn spring-boot:run` command ?

Comment: Tried this `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod" hello` but got error. Looks like the `hello` added as command line argument is not the correct way to pass.

Comment: Did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

Oke so this should work:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="hello,--spring.profiles.active=prod"
```

Comment: Will try it out and let you know