# how to debug spring application with gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, gradle

I am working on spring app and need to step through a controller method to see how it works. 
I am working in eclipse and building my app with `gradle bootRun` command.

How to run it in debug mode?

i tried `gradle bootRun --debug` but it's just debug log, not debug mode

i tried `gradle help --task bootRun` -- this gives me info about task
there i saw `--debug-jvm` option but when i run 
`gradle bootRun --debug-jvm` application doesn't start

Comment: Have you had a look at [Spring Logging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) yet? That would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Cain you detail 'application doesn't start" ? Is there an exception that you get ?

Comment: @alpar the site doesn't show in the browser. i see This site can’t be reached message

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, why are you using Gradle to run the app? Eclipse is the IDE, not Gradle...

Answer (score 108, accepted):

After you run `gradle bootRun --debug-jvm` the application is suspended until you connect your debugger to the port it is listening on (port 5005).

Comment: having an issue running gradle bootRun --debug-jvm. hangs at  Building 96% > :<project>:bootRun

Comment: this is the right answer, **suspended** means you need to click your **remote debug** button to connect to listener and then app start :P

Comment: By default, the debug port is 5005. How to start from a custom port say 5006?

Comment: Also, how to start without suspend?

Comment: @hariharankumar I haven't tested with `bootRun` specifically, but the `BootRun` task extends `JavaExec` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/run/BootRun.java), and I made it work with `JavaExec` passing `jvmArgs` to the task, so you could apply a similar logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946140/4850646

Answer (score 47):

As a response to dankdirkd's answer above: ([compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079415/1614555))

```
gradle bootRun --debug-jvm
```

will make the gradle build run in debug mode. That probably is not what you want. What you want to achieve is that the springBoot task starts your application in debug mode.

The spring boot task extends the gradle [JavaExec](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/55650bd61887cbfddabbb5167acbf9121682d7fe/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/springframework/boot/gradle/run/BootRunTask.java) task. You can configure the bootRun task in your build.gradle file to add a debug configuration like this:

```
bootRun {
  jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32323"]
}
```

For the build.gradle.kts this would look like this (with suspend mode disabled):

```
tasks {
    val bootRun by getting(BootRun::class) {
        jvmArgs=listOf("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=32323")
    }
}
```

If your server is within a cloud and you want to debug from local machine, you need to make sure that it allows connections from outside. Use below configuration in that case

```
tasks {
val bootRun by getting(BootRun::class) {
    jvmArgs=listOf("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:32323")
    }
}
```

Note that the address is now `0.0.0.0:port` instead of just `port`

Comment: I don't believe that --debug-jvm debugs the main gradle process. The bootRun process is a subclass of JavaExec which starts a child process in debug mode when receiving the --debug-jvm flag.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:jvmArgs

Comment: So i just add bootRun {
  jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32323"]
} into the build.gradle.   And that's it?

Answer (score 7):

For people hitting this via Google and wondering how to enable Spring's debug mode (normally done by `java -jar app.jar --debug`) and using Gradle, [here is how](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application.passing-arguments). This passes `--debug` to the main class which is how you turn on Spring Boot's debug mode which logs autoconfig classes among other things.

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--debug'
```

Answer (score 5):

For `build.gradle.kts` file you can also simply use below:

```
tasks.withType<BootRun> {
    jvmArgs = listOf("-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:32323")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer going under `Gradle tasks` and `right-clicking on the bootRun`. This is useful in the IDE compared to the terminal.

Comment: But how do u use Gradle tasks to run an application in debug mode? I also don't like the idea of using temrinal

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for IntelliJ example with gradle bootRun task:

1. Add following bootRun task definition to build.gradle file

```
 bootRun {
   jvmArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
 }
```

2. Run bootRun task
3. Once you get to the point where console/terminal says
   "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005"
   go to "Run --> Attach to Process..." and choose your app
4. Add breakpoints anywhere you want

Answer (score -1):

Define an executes a Java application in a child process.

```
task executeApp() {
    doFirst {
       println "Executing java app from Gradle..."
       javaexec {
           main = "com.mymain"
           jvmArgs = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=30000"]
       }
    }
}
```

Set your breakpoints in the java code. After execute the Gradle task.For example in Windows:

```
  .\gradlew.bat executeApp
```

The task waits until you attach the debugger. For example in Netbeans go to Debug->Attach debugger , set 30000 on port Field.

Comment: Thanks.  This indeed can allow developer to leaverage on breakpoint and trace thru codes. However, is there a way to combine both steps (run apps and attach debugger) Ina single execution of command or a button click. Cos Everytime when we make java code change, we have to stop the above process. Then execute these 2 steps manually. Seem like a chores to me.