# gradle: change default port from 5005

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, jvm

I want to debug some JVM instances that are running at the same time. I know that I can run gradle using `--debug-jvm` so that the JVM will wait until I start the IDE debugger so that it connects to the JVM but it uses port 5005 by default. That's fine for debugging one instance of JVM... but if I want to debug more than one instance, I'll need to define a different port from 5005. How can I achieve this with gradle?

Comment: Can’t you just use integrated tools to launch in debug mode with Gradle? I know IntelliJ just lets me start a gradle process and I can still debug the code.

Comment: Short answer: *no*. Long answer: No, because I'm using a script that is running many different things ending up with a gradle call.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I wanted to debug a specific file, so I included the following code in `build.gradle`:

```gradle
task execFile(type: JavaExec) {
    main = mainClass

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    
    if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
        jvmArgs "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y"
    }

    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}
```

and I can run with:

```
gradle execFile -PmainClass=com.MyClass -Dmyprop=somevalue -Ddebug=true
```

The custom `execFile` task receives:

- `-PmainClass=com.MyClass`: the class with the main method I want to execute (in the script, `main = mainClass`)
- `-Dmyprop=somevalue`: a property whose value be retrieved in the application calling `System.getProperty("myprop")` (in the script, `systemProperties System.getProperties()` was needed for that)
- `-Ddebug=true`: a flag to enable debugging on port 8787 (in the script, see the `if` condition, and also `address=8787`, but the port could be changed, and this flag name also could be changed). Using `suspend=y` the execution is suspended until the debugger is attached to the port (if you don't want this behaviour, you could use `suspend=n`)

For your use case, you could try to apply the logic behind the line `jvmArgs ...` to your specific task (or use `tasks.withType(JavaExec) { ... }` to apply to all tasks of this type).

Using this solution, don't use the `--debug-jvm` option because you may receive an error about the property `jdwp` being defined twice.

**Update (2020-08-10)**

To make sure that the code runs only when I execute the task `execFile` explicitly (so as to not run when I just build gradle, for example), I changed the code to:

```gradle
task execFile {
    dependsOn 'build'

    doLast {
        tasks.create('execFileJavaExec', JavaExec) {
            main = mainClass
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

            if (System.getProperty('debug', 'false') == 'true') {
                jvmArgs "-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:8787,server=y,suspend=y"
            }

            systemProperties System.getProperties()
        }.exec()
    }
}
```

See more at: [Run gradle task only when called specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347157/run-gradle-task-only-when-called-specifically)

Comment: With Java11 I created this kind of task with Spring Boot and Vagrant to enable remote debug: 

task debug(type: JavaExec) {
    main = mainClass

    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    jvmArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=192.168.133.10:5005,server=y,suspend=y"

    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon If you want to make sure that the code runs only when you call `execFile` explicitly, you can use the new code I included, in which the `JavaExec` task is created in a `doLast`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable and add standard Java debugger syntax e.g. to use port 8888:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888
```

Comment: This looked promising... but debugger fails to stop on a breakpoint I set on the project. If I use --debug-jvm and connect using port 5005, it stopped as expected. I guess there's something missing.

Comment: @eftshift0 Perhaps the Gradle daemon is running in the background. Can you try with `--no-daemon`?

Comment: that would be one option on the gladle call or an additional option on GRADLE_OPTS?

Comment: @eftshift0 yes, as per [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)

Comment: No change, unfortunately.

Comment: I _think_ this is setting the JVM args for the Gradle process/daemon, and not the forked JavaExec process. See Lucas Basquerotto's answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 - Directly pass the JVM arguments that start up the debugger

```
task exampleProgram(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  description = "Your Description"
  main = 'Example.java'  // <package>.<path>.<to>.<YourMainClass>.java

  // Change `1805` to whatever port you want.
  jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1805"]  
}
```

**If it doesn't work right away, try stopping all existing Daemons with `gradle --stop`** so Gradle isn't influenced by any past settings when building/running your project.

#### Option 2 - Use Gradle's `debugOptions` object

Alternatively, according to [Gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html#reset:%7E:text=Also%2C%20debug%20configuration%20can%20be%20explicitly%20set%20in%20debugOptions(Action)%3A), the following should also do the trick; however, [it didn't work for me](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16622). I'm including it for completeness and in the hope that it works in the future.

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    ...

    debugOptions {
        enabled = true
        port = 5566
        server = true
        suspend = false
    }
 }
```

*References:*

- JVM Debugger Args: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/gdabx/index.html
- Similar question: [how to debug spring application with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39490624/14765128)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 2 - Use Gradle's debugOptions object**

For Grails5 in build.gradle i put debugOptions into bootRun section:

```
bootRun {
  ...
  jvmArgs(
    // whatever extras you need...
  )
  debugOptions {
    //enabled = true
    port = 5566
    server = true
    suspend = false
  }
  ...
}
```

Then run grails with or without --debug-jvm switch at the end of arguments list to turn it on/off.

You may also uncomment "enabled=true" to always run in debug mode without passing --debug-jvm.