# How to debug a Jhipster/Gradle project on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gradle, jhipster, gradlew

On a Jhipster project, build with Gradle we have the "gradlew -Pdev" command to run the project on localhost.

But how to launch it since Eclipse (or other IDE), in order to get break points and debug it ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to debug spring application with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490624/how-to-debug-spring-application-with-gradle)

Comment: Not really... I launch by  "gradlew -Pdev". And when i write gradlew --help, the console don't propose --debug-jvm...

Comment: This is normal if you haven't modified anything in build.Are you a beginner with gradle?

Comment: Yes. It works finally. I add "bootRun {
  jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=32323"]
}" and connect to the good port with remote debug