# Debugging gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

We have a gradle project that has spring boot plugin. I'm trying to setup a remote debugger using Eclipse.

While setting up, I'm encountering Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. I have tried some suggestions online and the issue still remains. I can't recall the commands I have run using gradle command.

Any suggestions on how to fix the issue? Can someone provide a detailed step on how to fix this?

It's really time consuming debugging using a logger.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40661369/2834978

Comment: @LMC, on which directory should I run gradle bootRun --debug-jvmRun ? I have a gradle multi project.

Comment: I would say run the command as usual and add the `--debug-jvm` flag to it.

Comment: @LMC, I'm not actually running gradle bootRun via cmd. I'm running the application by going to gradle tasks tab in eclipse > application > right click bootRun > select Run gradle task.

Comment: I also tried to run the command in the root project but it's displaying Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependecyHandler.

Comment: I tried this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.21.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html

I tried jvmArgs but its displaying Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake

Comment: This works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318329/2834978