# Passing JVM args to SpringBoot bootRun Gradle task

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jvm

I would like to pass some JVM args to my Gradle bootRun task, namely `-Xbootclasspath`.  I have added:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

to my `build.gradle` file, but it doesn't like it when I run:

```
gw bootRun -Xbootclasspath/p:....
```

I get the error:

```
Unknown command-line option '-X'.
```

Am I perhaps running this incorrectly, or is `System.properties` not the correct approach for what I am looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working by using `jvmArgs`, as detailed in this SO question [ [How to pass JVM options from bootRun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079244/how-to-pass-jvm-options-from-bootrun) ]

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = ["-Xbootclasspath/p:<fully-qualified-path-to-jar>"]
}
```