# Passing JVM args from build.gradle in Spring Boot 2.0.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, configuration

I'm having some trouble trying to pass JVM arguments to a Spring Boot application from build.gradle file.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript ...

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

...
def devConfigFolder = "/abc"
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-DconfigFolder=$devConfigFolder"]
dependencies {
   ...
}
```

And the class where I try to use the placeholder:

```
@Component
public class PClass {

   private static final String CONF = "configFolder";
   @Value("${" + CONF+ "}")
   private String configFolder;
}
```

And this is the exception I'm receiving:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'configFolder' in value "${configFolder}"
```

I've tried with bootRun{jvmArgs}, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set these values in application.property /yml file and use that property key in @value annotation.

> application-prod.properties

```
configFolder="somefolder/path"
```

These property files can be set/modified in runtime.

You can take a look at this (5.1) section: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring 
Is that fine for you?? If not please let me know.

Comment: I know about application.properties/yml file, but I want to do something like this: def devConfigFolder;
if (condition) {
    devConfigFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/config/dev/"
} else {
    devConfigFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/core/src/config/dev/"
}       And I can't do a conditional check in a configuration file.

Comment: My problem is that I can't set the JVM args from gradle.

Comment: @Value("${user.dir}" == ""?"/src/config/dev/" : "/core/src/config/dev/")
Can you try like this?
May I know why you want to set in gradle specifically?

Comment: Because I'm using that placeholder in multiple places and I don't want to modify everywhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079244/how-to-pass-jvm-options-from-bootrun