Springboot @PropertySource accessing multiple property files failed at startup
i'm using springboot 2.7 and i tried to load 2 yml files by using :
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml", "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml"})

when i start the server, i have this error :
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application-default,dev.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
why "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml" --> dev.yml and not application-dev.yml ?

are you sure it is looking for dev.yml? it looks like you passed the profile as "default,dev" and the placeholder is substituting both in

Not sure how much you want to solve this particular problem vs just getting it to work, but an alternative to having multiple .yml files is to have one file, application.yml, with multiple profiles in it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149624/4963694

Because the spring.profiles.active property has the value default,dev. Therefore, the expression classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.yml is evaluated by Spring as classpath:application-default,dev.yml. If you specified the dev profile, you don't need to additionally use @PropertySource to load application-dev.yml, Spring will do it automatically, just like it loads application.yml.
See Spring Boot reference.
