# Specifying Java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm not very experienced with Maven and while experimenting with multi-module project I started wondering how can I specify Java version for all my child modules in parent Maven pom. Until today I was using just:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

...but when researching I found that you can also specify Java version in Maven compiler plugin, like that:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And then wrap this into plugin management tag to enable child poms usage of this. So the first question is this:

**What are the differences beetwen setting Java version in properties and in Maven compiler plugin?**

I couldn't find clear answer but in process of researching I found that you can also specify Java version in this way:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

...which suggest that compiler plugin is there even if I don't explicit declare it. Running `mvn package` outputs with

```
maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ testproj ---
```

...and some other plugins that I didn't declare.

**So are those plugins default, hidden part of Maven pom? Are there any differences between setting source/target in properties and in Maven plugin configuration element?**

Some other questions are - which way should be used (and when if they are not equal)? Which one is best for multi-module project and what happens if Java version specified in pom is different than version pointed in `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Related: [*“maven.compiler.release” as an replacement for source and target?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049980/642706)

Comment: Related: [*How do you specify the Java compiler version in a pom.xml file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16723533/642706)

Answer (score 450, accepted):

**How to specify the JDK version?**

Use any of three ways: (1) Spring Boot feature, or use Maven compiler plugin with either (2) `source` & `target` or (3) with `release`.

## Spring Boot

1. `<java.version>` is not referenced in the Maven documentation.
   It is a Spring Boot specificity.
   It allows to set the source and the target java version with the same version such as this one to specify java 1.8 for both :

   1.8

Feel free to use it if you use Spring Boot.

## `maven-compiler-plugin` with `source` & `target`

2. Using `maven-compiler-plugin` or `maven.compiler.source`/`maven.compiler.target` properties are equivalent.

That is indeed :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

is equivalent to :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

according to the [Maven documentation of the compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)
since the `<source>` and the `<target>` elements in the compiler configuration use the properties `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` if they are defined.

> [**source**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source)

> The `-source` argument for the Java compiler.
> **NOTE**: Since 3.8.0 the default value has changed from 1.5 to 1.6. Since 3.9.0 the default value has changed from 1.6 to 1.7
> Default value is: 1.7.
> User property is: `maven.compiler.source`.

> [**target**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target)

> The `-target` argument for the Java compiler.
> **NOTE**: Since 3.8.0 the default value has changed from 1.5 to 1.6. Since 3.9.0 the default value has changed from 1.6 to 1.7
> Default value is: `1.6`.
> User property is: `maven.compiler.target`.

About the default values  for `source` and  `target`, note that
[since the `3.8.0` of the maven compiler, the default values have changed from `1.5` to `1.6`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12317225&version=12341563).

## `maven-compiler-plugin` with `release` instead of `source` & `target`

3. The maven-compiler-plugin `3.6` and later versions provide a new way :

   org.apache.maven.plugins
        maven-compiler-plugin
        3.8.0
        
            9

You could also declare just :

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

But at this time it will not work as the `maven-compiler-plugin` default version you use doesn't rely on a recent enough version.

The Maven `release` argument conveys  `release` : a [new JVM standard option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627)  that we could pass from Java 9 :

> Compiles against the public, supported and documented API for a
> specific VM version.

This way provides a standard way to specify the same version for the `source`, the `target` and the `bootstrap` JVM options.
Note that specifying the `bootstrap` is a good practice for cross compilations and it will not hurt if you don't make cross compilations either.

---

**Which is the best way to specify the JDK version?**

The first way (`<java.version>`) is allowed only if you use Spring Boot.

**For Java 8 and below :**

About the two other ways : valuing the `maven.compiler.source`/`maven.compiler.target` properties **or** using the `maven-compiler-plugin`, you can use one or the other. It changes nothing in the facts since finally the two solutions rely on the same properties and the same mechanism : the maven core compiler plugin.

Well, if you don't need to specify other properties or behavior than Java versions in the compiler plugin, using this way makes more sense as this is more concise:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**From Java 9 :**

The `release` argument (third point) is a way to strongly consider if you want to use the same version for the source and the target.

**What happens if the version differs between the JDK in JAVA_HOME and which one specified in the pom.xml?**

It is not a problem if the JDK referenced by the `JAVA_HOME` is compatible with the version specified in the pom but to ensure a better cross-compilation compatibility think about adding the `bootstrap` JVM option with as value the path of the `rt.jar` of the `target` version.

An important thing to consider is that the `source` and the `target` version in the Maven configuration should not be superior to the JDK version referenced by the `JAVA_HOME`.
A older version of the JDK cannot compile with a more recent version since it doesn't know its specification.

To get information about the source, target and release supported versions according to the used JDK, please refer to [java compilation : source, target and release supported versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692748/java-compilation-source-target-and-release-supported-versions/51692749#51692749).

---

**How handle the case of JDK referenced by the JAVA_HOME is not compatible with the java target and/or source versions specified in the pom?**

For example, if your `JAVA_HOME` refers to a JDK 1.7 and you specify a JDK 1.8 as source and target in the compiler configuration of your pom.xml, it will be a problem because as explained, the JDK 1.7 doesn't know how to compile with.
From its point of view, it is an unknown JDK version since it was released after it.
In this case, you should configure the Maven compiler plugin to specify the JDK in this way :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>      
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>D:\jdk1.8\bin\javac</executable>                
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You could have more details in [examples with maven compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html).

---

It is not asked but cases where that may be more complicated is when you specify source but not target. It may use a different version in target according to the source version. Rules are particular : you can read about them in [the Cross-Compilation Options part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html).

---

**Why the compiler plugin is traced in the output at the execution of the Maven `package` goal even if you don't specify it in the pom.xml?**

To compile your code and more generally to perform all tasks required for a maven goal, Maven needs tools. So, it uses core Maven plugins (you recognize a core Maven plugin by its `groupId` : `org.apache.maven.plugins`) to do the required tasks : compiler plugin for compiling classes,  test plugin for executing tests,  and so for... So, even if you don't declare these plugins, they are bound to the execution of the Maven lifecycle.
At the root dir of your Maven project, you can run the command : `mvn help:effective-pom` to get the final pom effectively used. You could see among other information, attached plugins by Maven (specified or not in your pom.xml), with the used version, their configuration and the executed goals for each phase of the lifecycle.

In the output of the `mvn help:effective-pom` command, you could see the declaration of these core plugins in the `<build><plugins>` element, for example :

```
...
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default-clean</id>
       <phase>clean</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>clean</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default-testResources</id>
       <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>testResources</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>default-resources</id>
       <phase>process-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>resources</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default-compile</id>
       <phase>compile</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>compile</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>default-testCompile</id>
       <phase>test-compile</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>testCompile</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
  ...
```

You can have more information about it in [the introduction of the Maven lifeycle in the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Nevertheless, you can declare these plugins when you want to configure them with other values as default values (for example, you did it when you declared the maven-compiler plugin in your pom.xml to adjust the JDK version to use) or when you want to add some plugin executions not used by default in the Maven lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for extensive explanation, now it is much clearer to me. Also about <java.version> - I've seen this in some code snippet, maybe that was some custom property and I wrongly assumed that it is the way to declare java version, will stick to the `<maven.compiler.x>` property from now on.

Comment: You are welcome, with pleasure :)
Initially, It was not my intention to develop so much  but when I started, I could not stop :)
For ` <java.version>` it is very likely. See you and good maven !

Comment: "*it is not a problem if the JDK of your JAVA_HOME is compatible with the specified versions in the pom*" this is not (necessarely) true, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913775/maven-java-version-configuration-ignored-by-eclipse-idea) Stack Overflow thread for reference

Comment: I just came across `java.version` in the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-java-version). You can [see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml) it is simply used to set the `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` properties.

Comment: @Robin A. Meade thank you for the feedback. I use spring boot but i didn't know it. Personally I don t found it standard enough to be used or referenced as something to use. Spring boot offers some very interesting things but in some cases its features are very discutable. Overriding the name of a standard maven property to not fill both the source and the target jdk appears really as a bad idea as it is performed a single time for a application. You lose the standard to spare a simple xml line in your application. Woah ! What an idea...

Comment: The plugins should be enclosed within build tags.

Comment: @davidxxx -  I want to set the compiler source & target version by using the "<properties>" tag. The Java version is 10. How do I find out the exact version (1.10 or 10) to put in that tag ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 You find it in the official javac documentation of the 10 version : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javac.htm#JSWOR627. I had split that answer in two part as that becomes too big, you can also look at that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692748/java-compilation-source-target-and-release-supported-versions/51692749#51692749

Comment: What is the setting needed to upgrade Java EE Platform to JavaEE 8 version?

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions above worked for me straight away. So I followed these steps:

1. Add in `pom.xml:`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

2. Go to `Project Properties` > `Java Build Path`, then remove the JRE
   System Library pointing to `JRE1.5`.
3. Force updated the project.

Comment: Which version do you specify for Java 10 and above ? Is it 10 or 1.10 ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2  from java  9 and  above  versions  you need  to write  the  version number  as it is ( <version> 10 </version>), and for  the below versions, you have  to add 1. in front of the version (<version>1.5</version>)

Answer (score 3):

The below steps work for me like charm! so thought to share with everyone.

These are the lines i added in the pom.xml file to work with a basic project. I am using Java 12 (you can replace yours 11, 10, 1.8 etc).

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>12</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After changing the pom file please reload your project so that IDE can download/fetch the plugin to the project. (For IntelijIDEA: Right-click on pom.xml -> Go to maven -> Reload project).

please make sure to configure the desire version in your IDE as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using IntelliJ idea maven build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the alternative:

```
<properties>
    <javac.src.version>1.8</javac.src.version>
    <javac.target.version>1.8</javac.target.version>
</properties>
```

It should be the same thing of `maven.compiler.source/maven.compiler.target` but the above solution works for me, otherwise the second one gets the parent specification (I have a matrioska of .pom)

Answer (score 0):

Davids solution is correct and I would like to add the required setup for the Maven Compiler Plugin to compile main sources and test sources with an different Java release/language version.

The property `maven.compiler.release` is used by the Maven Compiler Plugin for main sources as well as for test sources. So, there is no way to compile test sources with an different JDK version than the main sources by simply setting a property (tested with version 3.11.0 of the Maven Compiler Plugin).

Therefore you have to overwrite the execution of `default-compile` and `default-testCompile` as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <configuration>
                <release>8</release>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <configuration>
                 <release>17</release>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Using this setup I was able to compile a single version of a multi module project with an different JDK version then the rest.

Why was it not enough for me to set `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.test` differently?

By setting only these properties, the comiler plugin was able to compile Java 11 code without any problem. And this is actually not what I wanted.

Answer (score -3):

For NetBeans IDE, changing project properties - (Jersey Service) - Categories > Sources >
Selected 'Source/Binary Format' as 1.8.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question: "Specifying Java version ***in maven***". Your answer, however valid, is answering something else.