# Java 11 Methods are not recognised in IntelliJ even after importing them correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have started a new Java 11 Project with the newest Version of the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5).

Everything seemed to work just fine for a while, but then some MethodCalls from imported modules were not recognised without any obvious reason. I've already tried invalidating the cache, but it did nothing. I'm also using maven 3.6.0 as I stumbled upon a post which suggested that the maven version that comes with said IDEA is not compatible with Java 11.

More specifically I tried using the method `Optional.ofNullable()` (same with `of()` or any other method of this class) which IntelliJ even proposed with AutoComplete. After auto-completion however IntelliJ seems to have forgotten it just now knew the method and proclaims: "Cannot find symbol: class ofNullable". The funny thing is: I can even Ctrl-Click Optional to be directed to the class and see that the method is actually there.

I'm at a loss.  Has somebody experienced a similar problem?

Comment: `File > Project Structure > Project` What are the SDK and language level set to?

Comment: Likewise, `File > Project Structure > Modules > {your module}` what is the language level set to?

Comment: In a Maven project, IntelliJ will automatically change these based on `source` / `target` options for the maven compiler plugin.

Comment: SDK and language level are both set to 11 (SDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2, language level: SDK - default(11 - local variable syntax for lambda representation)) and Modules language level is also 11 (Project Default (11 - local variable syntax for lambda representation))

Comment: @Sebi What's your IntelliJ version? Could it be that you are using a very old version which doesn't support Java 11.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 I just recently downloaded it after I set up a new computer

Comment: If you are using Maven, check to make sure the pom.xml is not overriding the compiler source and target versions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p

Comment: @Sebi if you just downloaded it, should the version be at 2019+ ?

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this problem as follows for the Spring boot project with the Gradle build tool.
IntelliJ-Idea version should support Java-11(related JAVA version).
Checks to perform from Bigger scope to narrower scope

- Check IDE support
- Check Build tool support and config
- Check Project settings
- Check Modules settings
- Check application run settings

1. **Add Java-11 SDK in Idea-IDE**
   [image]
2. **Change Gradle JVM to Java-11**
   `Preferences` --> `build,Execution,Deployment` --> `BuildTools` --> `Gradle`
   Old Intellij-Idea
   [image: Old Intellij Idea]
   New Intellij-Idea
   [image: gradle config]
3. **Change Project SDK and Language Level to Java-11**
   [image]
4. **Change Module Language Level to Java-11**
   [image]
5. **Change modules SDK to Java-11**
   [image]
6. **Application run configuration to Java-11**
   [image]