# Building Maven Project : Giving compilation Error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am new to Java/Maven, and I am trying to build a maven Spring Boot project, it was earlier working and was successfully creating jar package as well. But it suddenly stopped working and started giving Maven Compile error.

I know it has something to do with the `pom.xml` file. My best guess : Some changes in this file has caused it to fail.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.loanglide</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>drools-helloworld</name>
    <description>Springboot application</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12.0.1</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12.0.1</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <kie.version>6.1.0.Final</kie.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
         <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
           <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.28</version>
           <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>freemarker<!-- Legacy org-less group --></groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.905 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-08T01:52:48+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project springboot-helloworld: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 12.0.1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**Java Version**

```
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried many stackoverflow answer to similar question, but still not able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 12, add the following to Maven pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>12</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do I need to run a maven clean after this as well?

Comment: Yes, you have to run as mvn clean package or mvn clean install.

Comment: Started giving this error after i ran java-jar `jar file` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/loanglide/Drools has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Comment: This error comes up when you are using a jar file which is compiled in higher version of java and you have the project in lower version of java.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, anywhere i can understand the concepts of maven properly. I hate to be stuck in similar problems at times. If you can provide me some link where i can learn maven in deep and some common pitfalls, it would be great.

Comment: You can find lot of tutorials on Maven, now mostly used is Gradle. If you have time, you can learn both Maven and Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The properties `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` are used by many plugins on default lifecycle, as [compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#target), as you can see at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p).

You must try:

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

But if you want to override only this goal, you can configure it like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>12</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you are new with Java, keep in mind the new [versioning schema](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) so even you have installed the 12 version you can target the 11 LTS target if no new language feature is intended to be used.