# Setting the Java Version in Maven with system Java version as 11.0

Tags: java, maven, version, pom.xml, java-11

I am currently using jdk version as 11 in my local machine, Set using JAVA_HOME.

I need to run a maven project with java_version as 9. 
for doing the same took reference from https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version

here is my pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>8</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then i ran the command "mvn clean install" and the jar file generated is having java-version as 11 in its manifest file.
here is the snippet of Manifest file of the gemnerated jar

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.0
Built-By: test
Build-Jdk: 11.0.2
```

Why it is still picking java version as 11, why not 8?

Comment: You can perform `mvn -v` to check what version of Java is your Maven configured (`~/.mvnrc`) with. Also, note `release` as a flag would only be identified by Java-9 (value 9) and above. Besides which Java-8 is supposed to be `1.8` and not `8`.

Comment: I am not sure whether you know this: The JDK with which you build and the Java version you build for can be different. It is perfectly possible to build _for_ Java 8 _with_ JDK 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `java.version` in the POM `<properties>` section does not change the Java version used to compile with the `maven-compiler-plugin`. It is instead used by Spring Boot (see [Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p) for a related discussion).

Your build is still using the JDK 11 installed on your machine (this is reflected by the manifest attribute `Build-Jdk: 11.0.2`), however, **your code is actually compiled with source and target of Java 8**. JDK 11 knows how to compile against earlier versions like JDK 8, so your build is working fine as expected.

Comment: Say you have jdk1.8 somewhere in your PC, then if you run `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.8/ mvn build` then build will be from 1.8

Comment: @VishwaRatna Yes, but you can still use JDK 11 to compile against 8, 9 or 10. No need to switch the JDK.

Comment: Yeah,There is always a backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly change the java version on the go for the particular project so that it gets compliled with the version you want.

**Use** : `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk1.8/ mvn build`

Beside above you can explicitly set the version in your pom.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

set fist of all JAVA_HOME then execute the mvn clean install

```
export JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.15"
```

Then excute maven commands

```
mvn clean install
```

Note: export command will not work on CMD  use gitbash for this command.