# Determine the actual java version used in maven build

Tags: java, maven, jackson, pom.xml

Complementary to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p), **how to determine actual java version** used in `mvn compile`?

I am compiling [FasterXML/jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) as follows, but can't be sure of the java version:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind.git
$ cd jackson-databind
$ mvn compile
$ javap -verbose ./target/classes/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.class | grep "major"
  major version: 52
```

So according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file), the java version is `1.8`.
But when I grep the `pom.xml` I don't see that:

```
$ grep -wn "source" pom.xml
245:                <id>add-test-source</id>
248:                  <goal>add-test-source</goal>
252:                    <source>src/test-jdk14/java</source>
265:              <source>14</source>
```

I only see java 14 (?) What am I missing?

Comment: have you checked for `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>` or `<release>..</release>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent POM is `jackson-base` which does set the java version : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-bom/blob/e60567a0e778f749d9e39e2c245486a44fbc52f9/base/pom.xml

```
    <javac.src.version>1.8</javac.src.version>
    <javac.target.version>1.8</javac.target.version>

    <maven.compiler.source>${javac.src.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${javac.target.version}</maven.compiler.target>
```

You can inspect the fully evaluated POM with all the parents/dependencies/plugins/properties/etc using `mvn help:effective-pom`

Answer (score 1):

It's in the new release tag, not the source or compile -

You can reference it using the maven user property

NB Release overrides source and target values -
e.g. having source = 1.8, and target = 1.8, with release = 14,
compiles and releases in JDK 14

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.source}</release>
```

Comment: but then how come my `*.class` files say they have `major 52 (java 8)`?

Answer (score -1):

The version that is used by maven can be found in POM file like:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

or alternatively

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>    
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```