# gradle build.gradle issue with "version:"(forge modding)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

I am 10000000000% new to coding forge mods.
I am trying to run this command:

```
./gradlew setupdecompworkspace
```

I typed this in the terminal after going through the file path.
I get this error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/fred/Desktop/Mods-In-Progress/LearningMod/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/fred/Desktop/Mods-In-Progress/LearningMod/build.gradle': 15: unexpected token: 16.5 @ line 15, column 13.
     version =‘1.16.5-1.0.0’
                     ^
  
  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
FC-MBP3-3:LearningMod MYNAME$
```

My build.gradle file is this(I am not showing the whole thing btw):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '4.1.+', changing: true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
// Only edit below this line, the above code adds and enables the necessary things for Forge to be setup.
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version =‘1.16.5-1.0.0’
group = 'com.yourname.modid' // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = 'modid'
```

So, my question is how do I fix the error message. I have tried everything I can think of. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFVFqZo5t5Q
Thanks,
CreativeDrone

Also, I have an old mac. around OS version 10.8 Owo
Gonna get a new one soon
OK SO SOMEONE FIXED THIS PROBLEM BUT I AM STILL GETTING AN ERROR CODE THE ERROR CODE IS IN THE COMMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `''`, not `‘’`. Replace that line with `version ='1.16.5-1.0.0'`.

Comment: what about version =“1.16.5-1.0.0”

Comment: @CreativeDrone No, that's wrong too. You need `""`, not `“”`. `"1.16.5-1.0.0"` should be fine though.

Comment: Nope! Does not fix it

Comment: That's because you still didn't do it right. Copy and paste what I wrote, and if it still doesn't work, then post the new error.

Comment: PART 1:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/fred/Desktop/Mods-In-Progress/LearningMod/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/fred/Desktop/Mods-In-Progress/LearningMod/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
 ~some error stuff here that is too long~
  1 error

Comment: Part 2:* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
FC-MBP3-3:LearningMod MYNAME$

Comment: That means my change *did* fix it. You had another problem too, that was revealed by fixing the first one. As for your new problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67997715/7509065

Comment: Hello! I am making an actual Forge mod. The link you gave me was for spigot. I am USING FORGE. So, how do I fix the error(the new one)

Comment: btw I am actually trying to make a java 8 forge mod

Comment: The problem you had originally is solved. If you have a new unrelated problem, then ask a new question.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387774/minecraft-forge-mod-coding-terminal-will-not-let-gradle-install