# AWS java maven project to retrieve all the S3 keys

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, pom.xml

I have created a maven project for my AWS java development. I'm trying to get the list of all the files in a S3 bucket with a given prefix.

Here is my code:

app.java:

```
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Copy;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

    public static List<String> getObjectsListFromS3(AmazonS3 s3, String bucket, String prefix) {
        final String delimiter = "/";
        if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            prefix = prefix + delimiter;
        }
    
        List<String> paths = new LinkedList<>();
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket).withPrefix(prefix);
    
        ObjectListing result;
        do {
            result = s3.listObjects(request);
    
            for (S3ObjectSummary summary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                // Make sure we are not adding a 'folder'
                if (!summary.getKey().endsWith(delimiter)) {
                    paths.add(summary.getKey());
                }
            }
            request.setMarker(result.getMarker());
        }
        while (result.isTruncated());
    
        return paths;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bucket = "playground-us-east-1-1234567890";
        AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
    
        String prefix = "test";
        for (String key : getObjectsListFromS3(s3, bucket, prefix)) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I try to run the code `mvn package`, I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myapp: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/user/Desktop/myapp/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/App.java:[35,41] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Before, I was getting something similar error but I changed my `pom.xml` to java version1 compatible. But I don't understand this error and where I'm going wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an older API for Amazon S3. You should considering moving to Java API V2. V1 package names are:

```
   **com.amazonaws.services..**.
```

while V2 package names are:

```
  **software.amazon.awssdk.services...**
```

Amazon strongly recommends moving to V2:

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

You can find the POM file with the required dependencies in this Github repo:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3

All S3 examples are located here too.

**UPDATE**

Perform these Steps to get an Amazon S3 Java V2 code example (ListObjects) working:

1. Create a new Java Maven project in an IDE like IntelliJ.

[image]

2. Copy the POM file from the link above and drop it into your POM file.

[image]

3. Create a package named demo.

[image]

4. In the demo package, create a class named ListObjects.

[image]

5. Copy the code from here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/ListObjects.java

6. Add this code to your ListObjects class.

[image]

7. Run the code and see the output in the IDE:

[image]

Comment: I'm importing ```import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;``` but still I'm getting Compilation failure: ```package com.amazonaws.regions does not exist```, ```ackage com.amazonaws.services.s3 does not exist``` and so on..

Comment: See the instructions under Update in my answer.

Comment: ALso - feel free to connect to me in Linked IN. My Linked IN is under my profile. Then once connected, you can ask me Java API questions anytime in that tool.

Comment: I sent an invite to connect. I tried the above steps but still facing the same issue. ```package software.amazon.awssdk.regions does not exist```