# compilation error "diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5" when mvn install

Tags: java, installation, compilation, project, operator-keyword

I am developing a java project and every thing working fine, then once I needed to change the version of a library I use. When I run mvn install a compilation error appeared:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
> [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] /C:/Users/marwa/eclipse-workspace-photon/OntologyReuseProject/src/main/java/OntologyMatchingPackage/AMLMappings.java:[94,61] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
> (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
> [ERROR] /C:/Users/marwa/eclipse-workspace-photon/OntologyReuseProject/src/main/java/OntologyMatchingPackage/OntologyMatchingAlgorithm.java:[42,60] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
> (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
> [INFO] 2 errors

I am using Java 1.7 and also after this error I try to use 1.8 but the error still appear although the project is running correctly . How to solve this compilation error?

Comment: Add the relevant pom please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p)

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by a wrong or missing source version in the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration in your project's `pom.xml` file. You should set the `source` property to at least `1.7`, as the diamond operator was introduced in Java 7.
Example configuration:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: But still give me errors although the project runs normaly from eclipse 
The errors are:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project OntologyReuseProject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/eclipse-workspace-photon/OntologyReuseProject/src/main/java/OntologyMatchingPackage/AMLMappings.java:[8,11] package aml does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/eclipse-workspace-photon/OntologyReuseProject/src/main/java/AgentClasses/ConceptUtilityClass.java:[8,38] package org.coode.owlapi.rdfxml.parser does not exist

Comment: seems as it can not see some packages although they exist and nothing changed!

Comment: Solved. I had a java version mismatch ,so I have corrected it and i am able to build successfully.