# Maven build keeps failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I was able to run my service until I did `mvn clean install`. I don't know why but I think it might have to do something with my JDK version and Maven version.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rockysingh</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Eureka server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the error I get when I run `mvn clean install`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.521 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-28T23:15:57-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project eureka: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I tried changing the Java versions in my pom file to java 11 and my JAVA_HOME path to java 11 and still nothing. Everything was working fine until I ran `mvn clean install`. Now my project won't even run.

My IntillJ IDE uses openJDK-20 and even when I change that to 11 nothing worked. Now my service won't even start.

I'm using maven-3.9.5

Comment: Did you get the full log? Is that how the target version is set now? That’s not what it used to be but haven’t used Maven in years now ‍♂️

Comment: Run `mvn -v` and check the java version is what you think you are using.

Comment: As @seenukarthi mentioned, please add the output of the `mvn -v` command to your question.

Comment: You are not using JDK11+ because the message tells that you are using a JDK less JDK11 based on `invalid target release: 11`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following. Sometimes when you may need to compile a certain project to a different version than what you are currently using. The javac can accept such command using -source and -target. The Compiler Plugin can also be configured to provide these options during compilation. See - [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html#setting-the-source-and-target-of-the-java-compiler)

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You can also refer to this answer - [Specifying Java version in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p)

Comment: In case spring boot its the way to use `java.version` instead source/target

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work! I figured out my Maven version only works with Java 8. Now I have to downgrade everything to java 8.