# Running a Maven project using a specific Java version from multiple installed versions (Java 8, 11, 17)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I have multiple Java versions installed on my system (Java 8, 11, and 17), and I need to run my Maven project using a specified Java version. What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm looking for a way to configure Maven or set up the environment to execute my Maven project with a particular Java version from the multiple installed versions. I primarily work with Java 1.8, and I'd like guidance on how to specify this version when running my Maven build.

Comment: Maven looks at the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to define installed JDK. You can set this variable to make Maven works with the specific JDK version. Or you can use maven wrapper.

Comment: I have aliases like `j8` and `j20` to source the correct environment variables into the shell. You can do that with Powershell if you're on Windows

Comment: @ValerijDobler in which way? Because I'm using JDK 21 to build targeted JDK 8...

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved in multiple ways for example,

1. You can create multiple profiles in pom.xml and then override compiler plugin configuration in each profile as explained here [Specifying Java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882080/specifying-java-version-in-maven-differences-between-properties-and-compiler-p?rq=2)
2. You can create multiple bash scripts and provide specific JAVA_HOME env variable in that.

IMO, try a solution first and then post specific issues that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Java versions installed, you can can use tools like `Jenv` or `Sdkman` to specifically select a particular version for your project. You can find the relevent details for `Sdkman` [here](https://sdkman.io/usage) and for `Jenv` [here](https://www.jenv.be/). Of course you need also specify your desired Java version in your pom file. See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version) for more details.