# Building with IBM JDK

Tags: java, ignite

Building Apache Ignite's latest release is failing with following error :

```
WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] You are trying to compile Apache Ignite with inappropriate JDK version!
[ERROR] Detected JDK Version: pxa6480sr3fp12-20160919_01 (SR3 FP12)
[ERROR] JDK version should be 1.7.0-* or >= 1.8.0-u40.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However when I check JDK version, I see I am using IBM JDK 1.8 which clearly meets JDK requirement mentioned in the documents.

```
[user@machine apache-ignite-1.9.0-src]$ /opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3fp12-20160919_01(SR3 FP12))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160915_318796 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20160818_122998
GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160915_318796)
JCL - 20160914_01 based on Oracle jdk8u101-b13
```

Has anyone tried this before? Will I need to force Oracle JDK to make it work?

Comment: I think there is a mismatch between the java which Ignite is using and you are using? Can you try `java -version`?

Comment: Second output shown above is output for java -version itself.  Problem I think is,  maven enforcer is picking version information from second line instead of first line.  It may have been coded to parse output from standard JDK and may not have been tested on IBM JDK.

Comment: Instead of `/opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/bin/java -version`, try `java -version`. Lets make sure the `java` is pointing to `/opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/bin/java`

Comment: You can also try `which java`

Comment: Here you go :
`[user@machine apache-ignite-1.9.0-src]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6480sr3fp12-20160919_01(SR3 FP12))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20160915_318796 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20160818_122998
GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20160915_0912_B318796_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160915_318796)
JCL - 20160914_01 based on Oracle jdk8u101-b13 `

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032965/how-do-i-figure-out-and-change-which-version-of-java-maven-is-using-to-execute

Comment: `[user@machine apache-ignite-1.9.0-src]$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /opt/dev/maven/latest
Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: IBM Corporation
Java home: /opt/ibm/java-x86_64-80/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix" `

I think it is picking up correct java version from maven standpoint of view.

Comment: I think it is not able to compare "pxa6480sr3fp12-20160919_01(SR3 FP12) >= 1.8.0-u40"

Comment: That's what I am implying earlier (My first comment) . Though you brought good point where mvn -version detects the JDK version correctly but enforcer plugin detects JDK differently.   This is an inconsistency on maven implementation part.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-663. Take a look at this. I am not sure if it is on maven implementation part.

Comment: This is a two year old issue, and I would assume it is taken care in the latest build which is what I am using.

Comment: For now I am moving after installing Oracle JDK on my local machine. Thanks @prasanth for your help in troubleshooting so far.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Maven plugin takes build ID instead of actual Java version. Not sure why it behaves like this.

In any case, Apache Ignite was verified to be running on IBM JDK, but I doubt anyone ever tried to build it. You can give it a try by removing version validation from the POM.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I downloaded the binaries of ignite and it does come up with IBM JDK without any problem.